# AspectMock couldn't parse some of files

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

I got some error from codeception aspectmock vendor when run unit test with Yii2. The message display as below

> [RuntimeException]
>     AspectMock couldn't parse some of files.
>      Try to exclude them from parsing list.
>     There were following reasons for this exception:
>     Function trait_exists was redeclared (previousy declared in file /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php).

I know the message mean but don't know how to fix it. Does anyone have experience to solve it ?

Comment: Report your issue in https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock/issues

Answer (score 1):

Since this hasn't been answered here and was on their github page, exclude it in your bootstrap.php file when you initialize AspectMock\Kernel.

```
    $kernel->init(
    [
      'appDir' => $include_path,
      // Set the path to the class files.
      'includePaths' => [$include_path],
      // Exclude out phpunit tests otherwise aspect mock could have issues properly forming mocks.
      'excludePaths' => [
          // add files here
      ],
    ]
);
```

per [git hub](https://github.com/goaop/framework/issues/101)